# Java Eclipse JSOUP Error

Tags: java, eclipse, jsoup

There is a error with my code，I want to use Jsoup to get messages from a web，but it can't run successfully.I hope you can solve my problem，thanks a lot.

[image: This is the picture of the error]

Comment: There is no picture in your question.

Comment: I can see my  picture，maybe I didn't upload it successfully，still thank u.